# How to make json rpc request in Django?

Tags: json, django, api, rpc

I have to create a web panel for Voipswitch by using their API provided on this [website](http://docs.voipswitch.com/display/doc/VSR+Web+API+Integration+guide#VSRWebAPIIntegrationguide-getRetail). Visit to take a look at the api. They use json rpc 2.0 which I've never used before. How can I make requests in json rpc using Django as my framework for the panel?

I can capture the post data from users, but how do I implement it in an api call?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'requests' package, or urllib2

[https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpc2](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/